# In Gnome how to have multiple full screen areas on one screen?

Tags: linux, gnome, fullscreen, virtual-desktop

When working on big screens I often use Gnomes "snap window to left/right border" by dragging a window to the left/right side of the screen. This results in a partially maximized window which I find very convenient.

I wonder whether it's possible to **either** configure this behavior to have more of those areas in which I can maximize a window **or** do whatever is needed to display a configurable amount of *virtual desktops* on the same monitor.

**Note:** I already tried some tiling window managers like [xmonad](https://xmonad.org/) - but unfortunately most of them *force* all windows to be maximized (which is not always good) and you loose all the nice Gnome convenience.

So what I'm looking for is a way to have multiple 'fullscreen' windows on one display while keeping the default Gnome behavior.

**Another note**: [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/) comes very close to what I'm looking for with only two exceptions: it only resizes windows but leaves the space consuming title/menu bars and window decorators (in contrast to fullscreen mode). And it would be very nice to be able to define static areas which windows can be dragged to easily (which would make them 'fullscreen' in that area).

Comment: I cannot say that I fully understand your needs. Talking about not wanting maximized windows, but wanting 'fullscreen' windows? Also, you can place windows to left-right by pressing SUPER + left or right arrow. Arrow up to return to maximized. But check out: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/ if it fits your needs, if you are on a desktop you can place windows in corners etc using the keypad, or if having full size keyboard on a laptop. You can also move windows to the next screen etc.

Comment: What I try to achieve is quite simple but not easy to explain. I'd like to send a window in full-screen mode (i.e. no title/menu/decorators) but only in a part (e.g. top left quarter) of the screen. Tiling window managers do this, but they (often) force *every* window in full-screen mode which is bad in some cases (e.g. Virtualbox seamless mode). And I *really* like to stick with Gnome. So what would perfectly fit my needs would be an `xmonad` plugin for Gnome which *allows* floating windows.

Comment: Aah, I see. The closest I can think of is by using https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/ + Put Windows mentioned in the previous comment. Hopefully somebody more experienced chimes in.

Answer (score 2):

I am not using your environment, but below are some possibilities that might
apply.

**CompizConfig Setting Manager**

Set edge settings in grid using the CompizConfig Setting Manager
(`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`), using the
entry Window Management, plugin Grid to set the corner snap :

[image: CompizConfig Setting Manager]

For more info see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/310328).

**gTile**

The gnome extension [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/) says in the readme:

> Gnome-shell extension that improves window tiling capabilities of stock gnome-shell.
>   gTile is used to moves/resize windows on a configurable grid scheme.

When you click on the gTile icon it will open a dialog that lets you draw a region on an e. g. `1x3` grid. Once you have drawn the region gTile will move and resize the currently active windows to match that region on the real screen.

You can configure a hot key (for instance <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) to send the current window to a specific field in an `NxM` grid. In your case it could be the first field in a `1x3` grid. Likewise for the other two windows.

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018356)

**Other gnome extensions**

These extensions might have enough customization features for your purpose :

- [shelltile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/)
- [Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/)

Comment: I've bveeen using DisplayFusion on Windows. Gtile is the *exact opposite* of DisplayFusion, in that whenever you touch a window you will have to give it a placement. DisplayFusion allows defining several full screen areas - if you maximize a window in one it will fill that area. Drag it to another slot and it will be resized to the size of that. gTile does nothing like that.

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> I'm looking for is a way to have multiple 'fullscreen' windows on one display while keeping the default Gnome behaviour. … configure this behavior to have more of those areas in which I can maximize a window …  define static areas which windows can be dragged to easily (which would make them 'fullscreen' in that area).

fakexrandr provides exactly this capability and is worth trying.
https://github.com/phillipberndt/fakexrandr

nb: *something* in my ~/.config/ caused me problems.  It's worth testing with a clean user if it isn't working properly.

Comment: FakeXrandr has worked perfectly for me on Ubuntu 20.10